# how to create a new field to show, together with the SELECT'ed fields?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

These code lines filter all of the people that are over 50.

```
SELECT birthday FROM table_name
WHERE birthday < now() - '50 years'::interval
```

Together with this, I need to create an additional column, which shows the actual age.

Es.

```
  birthday     age
 2000-06-28    16
```

The column "age" shall be created together with the SELECT. It is NOT present in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific function called `age()`

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM age(birth_date)) AS age FROM ...
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html

[image]

[image]

Keep in mind: `age` subtracts from current_date (**at midnight**)

Comment: I tried with SELECT birthday , 2016 - EXTRACT(year FROM (birthday)) as age , 

but it does not count the month of birth. So not all of the ages are correct.

Comment: @Marco what do you mean by `it does not count the month of birth`?

Comment: it gives me all 49 as ages.

Comment: @Marco it's because `age` subtracts from current_date (at midnight). So you can do next to fix it `select EXTRACT(year FROM age(NOW(), NOW() - '50 years'::interval)) AS age;`

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this.

```
SELECT birthday , extract (day from((now() - birthday)/365)) as age
FROM table_name
WHERE birthday < now() - '50 years'::interval
```